# Dynamically created button text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating 2 buttons dynamically.

How can I change button text? Below is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(e){
    var thisbut = this.id;
    $.post('my.php',{ val: val1 }, function(done){
         document.getElementById(thisbut).innnerHTML = "Button Text New";
    });
});
```

Comment: not `.innnerHTML` it should be `.innerHTML`

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `innnerHTML`.

Comment: check `innnerHTML` typo..should be `innerHTML`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`innnerHTML` should be `innerHTML`, and your code will only work if the buttons all have a unique ID.

Instead you can directly use the element - there is no need to reselect it by ID:

```
this.innerHTML = "Button Text New";
```

Or jQuery:

```
$(this).text("Button Text New");
```

---

After the edited question:

You can assign the button to a variable like below and then use it in the success handler. Simply using `this` in the success handler won't work because the `this` context has changed, so by storing the button in a variable you can keep it for further use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(e){
    var thisbut = this;
    $.post('my.php',{ val: val1 }, function(done){
         thisbut.innnerHTML = "Button Text New";
         // or jQuery:
         $(thisbut).text("Button Text New");
    });
});
```

Comment: You'r solution did not work perhaps because of the $.post() request? Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. But the button text change only when `thisbut.innnerHTML = "Button Text New";` is above `$.post('my.php',{ val: val1 }, function(done){`. But it doesn't change the text inside the success handler.

Comment: If it's not working in the success handler then your success handler probably isn't running. Maybe my.php is erroring.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $(this) to get the id of element

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function(e){
    var thisbut = $(this).attr("id");
    document.getElementById(thisbut).innerHTML = "Button Text New";
});
```